# Iteration to Recursion in Python

Tags: python, if-statement, recursion, iteration

### How can I write this function Recursively:

```
def count(lst, value):
    c = 0
    for i in range(lst.size):
        if get(lst,i) == value:# get(lst, i) is predefined. It gives me the value at i in lst
            c = c + 1
    return c
```

Comment: This is very strange code for Python. the `for i in range()` is unusual, as is the `get(lst, i)`.

Comment: Instead of `get(lst, i)`, I would just suggest `list[i]`

Answer (score 1):

Seems you wanna count how many elements in `lst` is equal to `value`

IMHO, instead of doing this, you could get the count in just one short line:

`lst.count(value)`

Answer (score 0):

This should make the trick:

```
def recount(lst, value):
    if len(lst) == 0:
        return 0
    if get(lst,0) == value:
        return 1 + recount(lst[1:],value)
    else:
        return recount(lst[1:], value)
```

Comment: Or just use the integer value of the boolean: `return int(get(lst, 0) == value) + recount(lst[1:], value)`